# How to set the electric potential on a certain boundary to a certain value experimentally?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics

In electrostatic boundary value problems, usually the potential is set to some function or a constant on a certain boundary. It is never taught or told in textbooks how such assignment might be achieved experimentally.

For example how to set experimentally the potential on the boundary of a ball of radius $R$ to some constant $V_0$, where $V_0$ could be $-100 V$ or $0 V$ or $5 V$ say?

Comment: For that you always imply some reference body, for example, the ground. Then you connect your ball and the ground to a battery with the necessary voltage.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Can you show a pic for what you mean?

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding if this problem is about reference voltage or about the constant potential boundary condition.  Vladimir answered to the former.  The constant potential comes from the fact that charges in an isolated conducting volume will reorganize along any electric field line until there is are no more electric field lines within the volume - leaving the entire volume at a constant electric potential.  There are limitations to this statement of course.

Comment: If you have two equal balls charged equally, there will not be a potential difference between them. If you connect them with a wire, the current will not appear. Normally if you have one charged ball, we say it has this potential and mean "with respect to infinity" where the potential is equal to zero (again, a convention). So, only a potential difference matters. To have a difference, you have to have another (reference) body.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Okay potential on a boundary is 60 V say relative to 0. Now how to make the boundary of a ball to have that potential experimentally? I think the answer will depend whether the ball is a conductor or not.

Comment: If the ball is a conductor, you just connect it to a 60 V battery contact and connect the reference body (conductor too) to the other contact. When we name the battery voltage, we mean the potential difference between its two contacts, so it is really a relative (difference, not absolute) value. If the ball is a dielectric, you have to furnish/deplete it with electrons somehow (by rubbing or otherwise, I do not know).

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski So I connect the conducting ball to one of the terminals of the 60 V battery and I connect the other terminal of the battery to what? I do not think I need to connect the other terminal of the battery to anything right?

Comment: The other one - to your reference body. The potential is a relative notion. For example, if you battery is on the table and you do not touch it, its contacts have zero potential with respect to you. When you touch one terminal, you obtain the 60 V potential relative to the other terminal solely, not relative to the ground or something else.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Yes that is what I am saying, If I connect the conducting sphere to one of the-60-Volts battery terminals that means I have set the potential of my sphere to 60 volts relative to the other terminal. Now how to experimentally make the potential on the sphere a function of theta, the polar angle?